Apply Taylor's Theorem to show optimal solution of $f$

Let
$f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_1^2+\frac{1}{2}x_2^2+\frac{1}{2}x_3^2+x_1x_2+x_2x_3-2x_1-2x_2-2x_3$.
Apply Taylor's Theorem to prove that $\mathbf{x}^*=(1,0,1)^T$ is an
optimal solution to  the problem $\min f$, subject to
$x_1+2x_2+x_3\leq3,x_2+x_3\leq1,x_i\geq0$ for $i=1,2,3$.

My attempt:
$\nabla f(\mathbf{x}^*)=(0,0,-1)^T,\nabla^2f(\mathbf{x})=\begin{pmatrix}2&1&0\\1&1&1\\0&1&1 \end{pmatrix}$ for all $\mathbf{x}$.
Consider function derived by Taylor's Theorem: $$\begin{align*}
P(\mathbf{x})&=f(\mathbf{x}^*)+\nabla f(\mathbf{x}^*)^T(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}^*)+\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}^*)^T\nabla^2 f(\mathbf{x}^*+\theta\mathbf{d})(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}^*)\\&=-2.5-x_3+1+\frac{1}{2}((x_1-1)(2x_1-2+x_2)+x_2(x_1+x_2+x_3-2)+(x_1-1)(x_2+x_3-1))
\end{align*}$$.
So $P\geq-2.5-x_3+1+\frac{1}{2}((x_1-1)(2x_1-2+x_2)+x_2(x_1+x_2+x_3-2)+(x_1-1)(1-1))=-2.5-x_3+1+\frac{1}{2}((x_1-1)(2x_1-2+x_2)+x_2(x_1+x_2+x_3-2))$
Note: $\theta\in[0,1],\mathbf{d}=\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}^*$
However, I am stuck, how can I arrange the function so that I can apply the constrains, I want to show $P(\mathbf{x})=f(\mathbf{x})+c$ for some $c\geq0$ or $P(\mathbf{x})>f(\mathbf{x})$ for all $\mathbf{x}\neq\mathbf{x}^*$ and in the constrain.
Any hints will help! Thank!

Do you know the source of the problem?

It came from my course past exam papers (no solutions provided). I do it for practice, and prepare for my upcoming course.

Some thoughts.
Remark. Perhaps this answer is not what the OP wants,
since the way to apply Taylor's theorem seems unusual.
Let $g(x_1, x_2, x_3) := f(x_1, x_2, x_3) - x_2x_3$.
Let $\Omega := \{(x_1, x_2, x_3) : x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3 \le 3;\, x_2 + x_3 \le 1; \, x_1, x_2, x_3 \ge 0\}$.
First, we clearly have $f(x_1, x_2, x_3) \ge g(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ for all $(x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \Omega$.
Second, we have $f(1, 0, 1) = g(1, 0, 1)$.
Third, we claim that $g(x_1, x_2, x_3) \ge g(1, 0, 1)$
for all $(x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \Omega$.
Indeed, by Taylor's theorem, we have, for all $(x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \Omega$,
\begin{align*}
 &g(x_1, x_2, x_3) \\
 ={}& g(1, 0, 1)
 + \nabla g(1, 0, 1)^\top (x_1 - 1, x_2 - 0, x_3 - 1) \\
 &\qquad + \frac12 (x_1 - 1, x_2 - 0, x_3 - 1)^\top \nabla^2 g(\cdots ) (x_1-1, x_2 - 0, x_3 - 1)\\
 ={}& g(1, 0, 1) + (1 - x_2 - x_3)
 + \frac12 (x_1 - 1, x_2 - 0, x_3 - 1)^\top H (x_1-1, x_2 - 0, x_3 - 1)\\
 \ge{}& g(1, 0, 1)
\end{align*}
where
$$H := \begin{pmatrix}
 2 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
and we use $\frac12 (x_1 - 1, x_2 - 0, x_3 - 1)^\top H (x_1-1, x_2 - 0, x_3 - 1) \ge 0$ (actually $H$ is positive definite, however we can prove it without using the fact that $H$ is PD).
As a result, $f(1, 0, 1)$ is the minimum of $f$ on $\Omega$.
